# Flexbox not working in IE or mobile browsers

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox

I'm making this website: http://cycleswap.nl/

To stick the footer to the bottom of the page I'm using CSS flexbox, as explained [here](http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/). I make use of `display: flex`, `flex` and `flex-direction: column` to be more specific. This includes ALL existing legacy support and browser prefixes for flexbox I could find.

Everything works fine in Chrome and Firefox (Chrome mobile too), but in IE and the default Android browser I get all kinds of bugs.

**IE 11 (probably other versions too):** Just bugs out completely. The footer jumps to (almost) the top of the page. [SCREENSHOT](http://puu.sh/gE4VI/d5e05ea71a.jpg).

**Android browser:** Looks like `flex-direction` is completely ignored. The footer is displayed on the right side of the page. [SCREENSHOT](http://puu.sh/gE5g2/8fd618226a.jpg).

Now first of all, don't tell me these browsers don't support CSS flexbox, because they do. This is clear when opening [this W3Schools demo](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_flex-direction&preval=column) in both browsers. They both display the divs perfectly fine, including `flex-direction`. There must be a different problem.

My CSS is basically identical to [this](http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/).

Please tell me if you need any other information! Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I managed to solve it. For anyone wondering how:

I added `flex: 0 1 auto;` to the footer. This fixed it for IE.

For the Android browser, I added `display: box;` and `box-orient: vertical` to `body`. This added some missing legacy support which fixed the problem.

Comment: oh my gosh..I think I love you. This solved an issue on IE/Edge that i've been battling for the last two days!